# VimScript : Syntax highlighting plugins does not highlight

Tags: vim, plugins, syntax-highlighting

I'm making a syntax highligthing plugin for a language, I have this project tree :

```
Ark/
  ftdetect/
    Ark.vim
  syntax/
    Ark.vim
```

syntax/Ark.vim :

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
        finish
endif

syntax keyword ArkKeyword let mut  
highlight link ArkKeyword Keyword

let b:current_syntax = "arkscript"
```

And when I open a .ark file, those keywords aren't highlighted, and I can't figure out what is wrong, what should I do to make the syntax highlighting work ?

Comment: What is ftdetect script?

Comment: It is the file type detection

Comment: @Matt wanted you to show its content.

Comment: You are supposed to name things consistently: `ftdetect/ark.vim`, `set filetype=ark`, `syntax/ark.vim`, `let b:current_sytax = "ark"`, etc.

Comment: It works amazing, thx a lot